# Bootstrap 4, flexbox row in a container. Align vertically in the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm with Bootstrap 4 alpha 3 and I need a simply vertical alignment of this code **in page** with this code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#ff0000;">Prova</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h1 class="text-xs-center">HELLO!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: add this css will solve the issue .container h1{  margin : 0px;}

Answer (score 0):

If you can opt to use v4's flexbox mode, the columns will have the same height automatically.

Then to vertically align the text, add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to the desired column.

Comment: And for a full page container height, how can I do?

Comment: Try `html, body, .container {height: 100%;}` ?

Comment: Nothing. It just works if I use `height: 600px;` for example on `.row`.

Comment: Ok then, include .row to the above

Comment: Ok. Now it works. It is possible to find a natural way with Bootstrap 4?